# Posting data on a secure web page (https) using Curl

Tags: curl, visual-c++, libcurl

I want to write (post) data on a https web page using Curl library. I should mention that I am using visual studio c++. I am not sure, but as far as I understand, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS works for Http protocol. I used the following example given in the https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html. But it doesn't work. I am not sure, but as far as I understand, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS works for Http protocol.

```
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
    const char *data = "data to send";

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, 
    "https://antcolony.asvglobal.com/api/majid");
    /* size of the POST data */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, 12L);

    /* pass in a pointer to the data - libcurl will not copy */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);

    curl_easy_perform(curl);


    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Dear Daniel, By it doesn't work, I mean the string "data" doesn't appear on the Url. The web page shows a null string.

Comment: I enabled CURLOPT_VERBOSE. It gave me this massage "Connection #0 to host (nil) left intact".